# Google Error - Log-in not possible, when trying to log in with Python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[log-in not possible (windows error)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTkAf.jpg)

How can i avoid this problem.

Whenever i try to log in on any google page it´s giving me this error, that i can´t log in
and the browser might be not save.

Thx for your help

Comment: 1. Sharing link of screenshot is bad practice rather make it part of post itself if it is needed otherwise no screenshot of code at all. 2. Google is not made for automate neither any production sites. Do not try to automate them. 3. There is TOS(terms of service) of every site which warns about not to automate them or not to scrape them. 4 Please read [mcve] and follow that in every future post it will help you to get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you retrieve cookies from your usual browser and add it to selenium browser to fake your session.
Retrieve cookies from your browser as a JSON (with driver.get_cookie() or plug-in [EditThisCookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg))

Then add cookies to your browser with the method :

```
with open("your_cookies.json", "r") as f:
     cookie_json = json.load(f)
driver.add_cookie(cookie_json)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly logging in to Google, you can do this through another service.
[For example, when you log in with google from here, google will not block you.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFX0x.jpg)